# Ternary combinatorics with no adjacent items of equal value

Tags: combinatorics

**Background**: I was given this problem second-hand, with the note that the answer should be in the thousands, but I can barely get anything more than 200.

**Question**: How many permutations of AAABBBCCC can you make, where no two letters are adjacent?

**My attempt**:

> Break up the 9-letter string into two parts: the first five; and the remaining four.
>
> **Case 1**: All three of one letter is used up in the first five positions. (e.g. ABACA~)
>
> > **Sol'n**: The first five will be a form like ABACA~ or ACABA~, which forces only two remaining possibilities for the remaining four: ~BCBC or ~CBCB
>
> $\Rightarrow (3*2*1*1*1)*(2*1*1*1)$
>
> = 12 permutations
>
> **Case 2**: Third letter type first occurs in 5th position (e.g. ABABC~)
>
> > **Sol'n**: Since the 5th position is the 3rd letter type, the first two letter types only have two other permutations for 1st~4th positions: ABAB~ or BABA~. Likewise, the 3rd letter type can only reoccur at 7th and 9th positions.
>
> $\Rightarrow (3*2*1*1*1)*(2*1*1*1) $
>
> = 12 permutations
>
> **Case 3**: The 5th position is occupied by the second occurrence of any letter. (e.g. ACBAB~)
>
> > **Sol'n**: This should cover all cases not already covered by cases 1 and two, meaning there are $(3*2*2*2*2)-(6+6) = 48-12 = 36$
> >     possibilities for the first five positions. For the remaining four,
> >     the only repeated letter is the singleton in the first set of five.
> >     Let C be the singleton in the first four positions (if singleton C is in the 5th position, we'd be looking at Case 2). Then there are
> >     only five possibilities for the remaining four (six, minus the one
> >     where the 5th and 6th positions are the same letter): CACB, CBCA,
> >     CABC, CBAC, <s>ACBC</s>, BCAC
>
> $\Rightarrow (36)*(5)$
>
> = 180 permutations
>
> Summing up our three cases, we get $180 + 12 + 12 = 204.$

Where am I going wrong? Are there cases I'm failing to consider? ...Or is my friend wrong for thinking the solution should be in the thousands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You and your friend are both wrong.

In your analysis of Case 3, you say:

> This should cover all cases not already covered by cases 1 and two,
>   meaning there are (3∗2∗2∗2∗2)−(6+6)=48−12=36(3∗2∗2∗2∗2)−(6+6)=48−12=36
>   possibilities for the first five positions

This is incorrect. For example, a case like ABABA is not included in the previous two cases and should not be included in this one either. Excluding these six cases, you get $30 \times 5 = 150$ for case 3, giving a total of 174. This total can be easily verified with a program.

Also, it is pretty easy to see that the answer could not have been in the thousands. There are only $\frac{9!}{3!3!3!} = 1680$ permutations of the string, so the number of valid permutations have to be even fewer.

Comment: Ahh, I knew sth was off with Case 3! Thanks for finding the hole in my logic! :D